# Python class attribute referencing

Tags: python, class

This is a sample code that i found from one of the python class tutorial.

```
class MyClass:
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'

print MyClass.f
print MyClass.i
```

Once i run this, i am expecting the output result of "hello world" and "12345". But instead i am getting this

```
>>> 
<unbound method MyClass.f>
12345
>>>
```

why is it not giving me 'hello world'? How do i change my code so that it will print out "hello world"? P.S i have no clue about python classes and methods and just started learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an instance of MyClass first.

```
test = MyClass()
print test.f()
print MyClass.i
```

You don't need to create an instance of MyClass for i, because it is a class member, not an instance member.

Comment: This is right, but you might also want to mention that OP needs to *call* the method as well, otherwise python will just print out the information *about* the method rather than running it's code.

Answer (score 1):

Always a function is called by its name, which is represented by `()`. So use
`MyClass.f()`